# Improving spacing and format of rectangles in circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

As can be seen in following figure the above and lower rectangles touch one another (The rectangles suppose to be on circle perimeter).

1. Is there a way to make the rectangles seem more spacey?
2. Is there a way to change the shape of central rectangle to a 3D box (the front face contains the text)?
3. Is there a way to improve the figure?

Code:

```
[import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

# Create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Set the limits of the plot
ax.set_xlim(-150, 150)
ax.set_ylim(-150, 150)

# Draw the big circle
circle = patches.Circle((0, 0), radius=100, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(circle)

# Draw the box
box = patches.Rectangle((-50, -15), 100, 30, facecolor='white', edgecolor='black')
ax.add_patch(box)

# Write the text inside the box
text = "AAAA VVVV BBBB CCCC"
ax.text(0, 0, text, fontsize=8, fontweight='bold', ha='center', va='center')

# Define the list of texts for each rectangle
rectangle_texts = \[
   "Exxxxxxxxx", "Mxxxxxxxxx", "Dxxxxxxxxxxx", "Nxxxxxxxx", "Axxxxxxxx", "Mxxxxxxxxx", 
   "Ixxxxxxxxxxx", "Txxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Cxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Dxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Dxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
   "Axxxxxxxxxx", "Ixxxxxxxxx", "Txxxxxxxxxxx", "Exxxxxxxxxx"
\]

# Draw transparent rectangles on the perimeter of the circle
num_rectangles = 14
angle = 2 * np.pi / num_rectangles
rectangle_width = 40
rectangle_height = 20

for i in range(num_rectangles):
    theta = i * angle
    x = 100 * np.cos(theta)
    y = 100 * np.sin(theta)
    rectangle = patches.Rectangle((x - rectangle_width/2, y - rectangle_height/2), rectangle_width, rectangle_height,
                                  facecolor='none', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_patch(rectangle)
    ax.text(x, y, rectangle_texts\[i\], fontsize=5, fontweight='bold', ha='center', va='center', color='black')

# Remove the axis ticks and labels
ax.axis('off')

# Display the plot
plt.show()][1]
```

[image: Figure Output]